# Xvfb plugin to run multiple job instances concurrently on Jenkins

Tags: firefox, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, xvfb

I have a job in Jenkins that runs UI tests written in Selenium. The job can run multiple instances of it concurrently. I am running into a problem while trying to use Xvfb (the [Xvfb plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin) or otherwise).

**Using the Xvfb plugin**

The configuration is as below.
[image]
The plugin assigns the same display port to 2 concurrent job instances, and then one fails.

From the Xvfb log (note displayfd is 2 and screen is 0 in both cases):

```
Xvfb starting$ /usr/bin/Xvfb -displayfd 2 -screen 0 1024x758x16 -fbdir /srv/jenkins/xvfb-86-2156913754362856583.fbdir
Xvfb starting$ /usr/bin/Xvfb -displayfd 2 -screen 0 1024x758x16 -fbdir /srv/jenkins/xvfb-87-5845090375656014678.fbdir
```

One of the above 2 job instances fails. The failure message is this:

```
02:11:51 _XSERVTransSocketINETCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
02:11:51 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
```

How can this error be fixed so that the concurrent instances run without any issue?

Further, I wonder how Xvfb plugin does the association of the display to the running browser instances (Firefox in this case). Does it do `export DISPLAY=:xx` internally, where xx = the display port as computed by the plugin?

**Command line (not using Xvfb plugin)**

The second way I tried is not to use the plugin and run Xvfb directly using the CLI. I used the Jenkins env variable BUILD_NUMBER to ensure unique display association to the job instance.

```
export DISPLAY=:${BUILD_NUMBER}
Xvfb :${BUILD_NUMBER} -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
```

Xvfb starts up fine in both job instances, but the tests fail with this.

```
Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/local/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
Error: cannot open display: 0:0
```

It appears the tests are still trying to use display 0:0.

Any help to fix this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about this, but on your command line implementation don't you need a unique number after the `-screen` argument as well? For example: `Xvfb :${BUILD_NUMBER} -screen ${BUILD_NUMBER} 1024x768x24 &`. I'm a newb to xvfb though, so I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use Display environment variable in Jenkins, the same Xvbf has started with? In my case it worked and I followed the instructions, described in this article [headless execution selenium tests in Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/headless-execution-selenium-tests-jenkins)